# LDAP search in java: DN contains ,

Tags: java, ldap, escaping

I'm currently running into issues when searching for entries where the DN contains a comma:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(dn, "=");
Attributes searchAttributes = new BasicAttributes(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
Enumeration results = ctx.search(baseDn, searchAttributes);

if (results.hasMoreElements()) {
  // ...
}
```

I tested both `dn=first,second` as well as `dn=first\,second`, and **although the search runs correctly, I never get any results back**. The same baseDn and dn works correctly in Eclipse/Apache Directory Studio LDAP Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends of libraries, for example by using Novell ldap.jar is constuctor

```
searchResults = lc.search(searchBase, searchScope, searchFilter, null, false);
//private String searchFilter = "(objectClass=*)";
```

again depends or libraries, because maybe Directory Studio LDAP Browser has own driver, and some methods are implemented another maybe not, for example with ldap.jar is able to seach in ActiveDirectory

basically all libraries (including Java driver for Windows ActiveDirectory) contains tons of examples packed with library, for most importand of methods which are implemented into driver

EDIT:

hmmm, but there are two relevant

1/ access for context given by admin (between enviroments)
2/ with ActiveDirectory (always) and with (old PC) test enviroment for LDAP I must force for thread(s) some small pause

```
private void readData() {
        searchResults = new LDAPSearchResults();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(450);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Profylaxia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            searchResults = lc.search(searchBase, searchScope, searchFilter, null, false);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Profylaxia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            int noResult = searchResults.getCount();
            System.out.println("  noResult : " + noResult);
```

// thenafter I can able to start Iterations....

Comment: @MrG you are welcome, for these info I wait mera than 2weeks on severals forums :-)

Answer (score 1):

The quoting rules for ldap queries can be found at http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm

I'm using the following code snippet to query the cn, should work teh same for the dn:

```
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=" + query + "))";
    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    String[] resultAttributes = {"cn", "distinguishedName", "displayName", "lastLogon", "description"};
    searchControls.setReturningAttributes(resultAttributes);
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    NamingEnumeration ne = getContext().search(root, searchFilter, searchControls);

    List<DirectoryUser> result = new ArrayList<DirectoryUser>();
    while (ne.hasMoreElements()) {
        SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult)ne.nextElement();
        Attributes attrs = searchResult.getAttributes();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You should use query arguments here. (cn={0}), and add new Object[]{query} as the argument-list in the search() method.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks, that would probably be better when searching for an exact match, most of the time I'm searching for substrings contained in a field, the '*' would then get escaped when using parameters. The `searchFilter` above is actually a parameter to a common search method.