# InvokeLater not outputting updating value

Tags: java, swing, ldap, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I'm using invokelater to update a value on button click, but the value is only changing when I run another instance of the GUI. I'm running the invokelater method outside the main method so I'm not sure why the value won't update. Any help is appreciated.

```
private void threadStart() {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          testLabel.setText(CN);
        }
      });
    }
```

I'm using the created method here:

```
searchComputerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                threadStart();
                String line;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            etc...
```

You can view the full class here:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.naming.InvalidNameException;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MISControlPanel {

    JFrame frame;
    static JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JLabel selectedComputerFromAD = new JLabel("testing");
    String sCurrentLine = null;
    String CN = null;
    JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("test");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MISControlPanel window = new MISControlPanel();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     * 
     * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
     */
    public MISControlPanel() throws IOException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.RED);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 658, 618);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setTitle("MIS Advanced Computerers");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\anoc5f\\Desktop\\Output.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");
        JButton searchComputerButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchComputerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                threadStart();
                String line;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                String s = null;

                Process p = null;
                /*
                 * try { // p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                 * "cmd /c start c:\\computerQuery.bat computerName"); } catch
                 * (IOException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e1.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
                try {

                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\computerQuery.bat");

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
                StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                        .getInputStream()));

                try {

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println(line);

                        // textArea.append(line);

                        String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
                        LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
                        String commonName = (String) ldapName.getRdn(
                                ldapName.size() - 1).getValue();

                    }
                    ComputerQuery.sendParam();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                } catch (InvalidNameException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally

                {
                    try {
                        fw.close();

                    }

                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {

                    in.close();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }

                ComputerQuery.sendParam();

            }
        });

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "resultofbatch.txt"))) {

            final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("CN=([^,]+).*");
            try {
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] tokens = PATTERN.split(","); // This will return
                                                            // you a array,
                                                            // containing the
                                                            // string array
                                                            // splitted by what
                                                            // you write inside
                                                            // it.
                    // should be in your case the split, since they are
                    // seperated by ","
                    // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                    CN = sCurrentLine.split("CN=", -1)[1].split(",", -1)[0];

                    System.out.println(CN);
                    testLabel.setText(CN);
                }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        // SwingUtilities.invokeLater(updateCN());
        searchComputerButton.setBounds(419, 19, 89, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(searchComputerButton);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(285, 19, 124, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblComputerName = new JLabel("Computer Name:");
        lblComputerName.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblComputerName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblComputerName.setBounds(159, 13, 124, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblComputerName);

        JLabel lblSelectedComputer = new JLabel("Selected Computer:");
        lblSelectedComputer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblSelectedComputer.setBounds(205, 78, 143, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSelectedComputer);
        java.net.InetAddress localMachine = null;
        try {
            localMachine = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        textArea.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        textArea.setFont(textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        textArea.setBounds(10, 387, 632, 191);
        textArea.setEditable(false); // might cause design view not to come up
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("SSO REPAIR");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(36, 183, 132, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Batch File Fixes");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(53, 158, 115, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblIpAddress = new JLabel("IP Address:");
        lblIpAddress.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblIpAddress.setBounds(261, 104, 102, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblIpAddress);

        JLabel label = null;
        try {
            label = new JLabel(Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()); // Get
                                                                                // User
                                                                                // ID
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        label.setForeground(Color.RED);
        label.setBounds(349, 105, 99, 21);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel lblPcCommunication = new JLabel("PC Communication");
        lblPcCommunication.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblPcCommunication.setBounds(279, 158, 115, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPcCommunication);

        JButton btnPingComputer = new JButton("PING");

        btnPingComputer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }

        });

        btnPingComputer.setBounds(306, 183, 64, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnPingComputer);

        JButton remoteAssistanceButton = new JButton(
                "Remote Assistance by PC Name");
        remoteAssistanceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });

        remoteAssistanceButton.setBounds(215, 251, 246, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(remoteAssistanceButton);

        JButton btnPingIndefinetely = new JButton("PING INDEFINETELY");
        btnPingIndefinetely.setBounds(260, 217, 156, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnPingIndefinetely);

        JButton btnRdcByIp = new JButton("RDC by IP Address");
        btnRdcByIp.setBounds(261, 353, 156, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnRdcByIp);

        JButton btnRdcByName = new JButton("RDC by PC Name");
        btnRdcByName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnRdcByName.setBounds(248, 319, 180, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnRdcByName);

        JLabel lblLoggedInOpid = new JLabel("Logged in OPID:");
        lblLoggedInOpid.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblLoggedInOpid.setBounds(228, 127, 135, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblLoggedInOpid);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(System.getProperty("user.name")
                .toUpperCase());
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(348, 130, 86, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JButton btnHiddenShare = new JButton("HIDDEN SHARE");
        btnHiddenShare.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        btnHiddenShare.setBounds(484, 183, 132, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnHiddenShare);

        JLabel lblAdditionalTools = new JLabel("Tools");
        lblAdditionalTools.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblAdditionalTools.setBounds(526, 157, 126, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAdditionalTools);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Remote Assistance by IP Address");
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(215, 285, 246, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton gpUpdate = new JButton("GP UPDATE");
        gpUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        gpUpdate.setBounds(36, 217, 132, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(gpUpdate);

        JButton btnForced = new JButton("NURMED REG FIX");
        btnForced.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnForced.setBounds(36, 251, 132, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnForced);

        JButton btnCleaConsoler = new JButton("CLEAR");
        btnCleaConsoler.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textArea.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnCleaConsoler.setBounds(563, 353, 79, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCleaConsoler);

        JLabel lblOpid = new JLabel("Find Computer by OPID:");
        lblOpid.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblOpid.setBounds(104, 53, 180, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblOpid);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(285, 50, 124, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Search");
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(419, 50, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);
        testLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        testLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));

        testLabel.setBounds(358, 78, 150, 24);
        frame.getContentPane().add(testLabel);

    }

    private void threadStart() {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

              testLabel.setText(CN);
            }
          });
        }
}
```

Comment: *"You can view the full class here:"*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  And **post it **here** rather than at an external link that might go stale and many will not visit.

Comment: I can post the full class within the forum no problem, I just feel like it's overkill when I'm trying to point out key parts of the code. I updated the post to include the class as well. Anyways...I know you were helping me earlier to try and resolve this. Do you have any clue what it is I'm doing that's causing the value not to update within the same instance of the GUI?

Comment: The idea is to make the code runnable for others to see the problem.  Do you really think things like `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\anoc5f\\Desktop\\Output.txt");` are part of the actual problem?  If so, you can debug this in the command line (with no GUI).  If not, factor it out of the MCVE (hard code some data).  Note that an MCVE is not a 'code dump' like included above, but is honed down to only the code needed to see the problem.  Do some more trimming,

Comment: there are two problems, if LDAP returns something, [put Thread.sleep(500) for testing purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6123001/714968)

Comment: LDAP does return something, but I can only see the return if I open a new instance of the GUI to update the value for the jLabel 
"testLabel"

Comment: You seem to have a race condition which means you're not controlling your threads so that one waits for the other to reach a man state. Personally, I'd throw a lot of it out and use a SwingWorker instead